How to import libv2ray.aar to flutter project and use it on kotlin activity?
I want to use libv2ray.aar in flutter project.
Then use classes on java or kotlin activities.
i did before somethings on gradle files:
add flat dir ->
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
  }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation files('libs/library.aar')
}


and more codes....

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':generateDebugRFile'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':debugCompileClasspath'.
Failed to transform library.aar to match attributes {artifactType=android-symbol-with-package-name}.
> Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /home/rezahamdi/Documents/Projects/current/process/utah_vpn/android/libs/library.aar.
> Transform's input file does not exist: /home/rezahamdi/Documents/Projects/current/process/utah_vpn/android/libs/library.aar. (See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158753935)

